# Rails - can't access custom join data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a really complicated query (which finds bus connections between two towns) and I haven't got any idea how to access data from joins (I'd like to know at which stop does the connection start and at which does it end). Is it possible to access this data using ActiveRecord?

```
Course.joins("INNER JOIN stop_times as start_stop ON start_stop.course_id=courses.id")
.joins("INNER JOIN stop_times as end_stop ON end_stop.course_id = courses.id")
.joins('INNER JOIN stops as start_stopi ON start_stop.stop_id = start_stopi.id')
.joins('INNER JOIN stops as end_stopi ON end_stop.stop_id = end_stopi.id')
.where('start_stop.hour>= ? OR (start_stop.hour>= ? AND start_stop.minute>= ?)',hour,(hour+1)%24,minute)
.where('start_stopi.town_id = ? and end_stopi.town_id = ?',start_town,end_town)
.where('start_stop."order"<end_stop."order"').order('start_stop.minute ASC').order('start_stop.hour ASC')
```

EDIT:
I've managed to rewrite it to use active record joins, although it broken my names, it works.

```
Course.joins(end_stop_times: :stop).joins(start_stop_times: :stop)
.where('start_stop_times_courses.hour>= ? OR (start_stop_times_courses.hour>= ? AND start_stop_times_courses.minute>= ?)',hour,(hour+1)%24,minute)
.where('stops_stop_times.town_id = ? and stops.town_id = ?',start_town,end_town)
.where('start_stop_times_courses."order"<stop_times."order"')
.order('start_stop_times_courses.minute ASC').order('start_stop_times_courses.hour ASC')
```

Using this new query models are:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :carrier
  has_many :end_stop_times, class_name: 'StopTime'
  has_many :start_stop_times, class_name: 'StopTime'

class Stop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :town

class StopTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stop
  belongs_to :course
```

Comment: Is there any reason, why course has_many end_stop_times and start_stop_times?

Comment: yes, otherwise I couldn't use double join with the same table.

Comment: My question was why has_many, not has_one? It seems to me your model design is slightly dodgy and it can quickly go wrong. As i understand it, you have a number of courses, each course is between two stops (correct me if I am wrong). In this case your course should have two has_one associations + starting and ending time, no need for StopTime model. Thing get more complicated when your course might have a number of stops (then you need to use some smart representation of a graph), but even then there should be only one start stop and one ending stop.

Comment: Actually my courses are not exactly between two stops and I want to find connection between any combination of these stops.

Comment: Maybe you've got an idea about this weird uniq result: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/925118/Zrzut%20ekranu%20z%202013-09-16%2019%3A02%3A54.png . When I count objects with count after uniq it shows 3, but when I perform each there are 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add sth like:

```
your_query.select('courses.*, start_stopi.id as start_stop_id, end_stopi.id as end_stop_id)
```

and then you can access it by calling start_stop_id and end_stop_id on course object.

However you should probably use association for this kind of operations. Could you show us you models?

Answer (score 0):

Check your log for the output of this query, you should find that it starts with `select courses.*` - therefore it will not bring through data from the included tables.

You can add some `select other_table.some_column` statements to your query, but this isn't the rails way.

I would suggest you separate your scope into the relevant models - put scopes in the `stop_times` model (and others) so that you can call the scopes on the object you actually want to get data from.

Answer (score 0):

When you're constructing custom SQL of that complexity I think you've taken the Rails-way of doing things too far. You're using practically no activerecord association information to construct it, and you've built a programming construct that is horribly ugly and difficult to read.

I'd advise that you rewrite it as well formatted SQL

```
results  = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
"select c.*
 from   courses    c
 join   stop_times ss on ss.course_id = c.id
 join   stop_times es on es.course_id = c.id
 ... etc ...
 where  (start_stop.hour  >= #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(hour)} or
        ... etc ...")
```

Now it could be that you can improve your models and associations to the point where this level of complexity is not required (eg. the associations between courses, stop_times (start) and stop_times (end) could probably be encapsulated in activerecord pretty well, but at the moment you seem to be falling between the pure SQL and the pure activerecord approaches in a very uncomfortable way.

Comment: "encapsulated in activerecord pretty well" did you mean using this joins(end_stop_times: :stop).joins(start_stop_times: :stop) ?

Comment: @ukasiu I guess the end result might end up looking like that, but my brain only works with hash-rockets still, and is naturally repulsed by this new syntax.